# google map usage

Tags: google-maps

Does any have nay information on usage of google map in busines/commerceial use?
Is there a limit on how many times an individual can use the google map to view daily info, when used commercially.

or the restriction is set on the business or the ip?

I am planning to display information on google map , where other userd can view such information using google maps.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i dont think there is a limit for those services

Comment: not with direct google map service, but if you looking to use google map API then there are limitations; that is 25,000 requests/day anything more would be charged https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_pricing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Terms of Service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html):

> 10.1.2 Restrictions against Commercial Use.
>
> (a) No Fees. You must not charge users or any other third party any
>   fee for the use of the Maps API Implementation, the Service, or the
>   Content, except as permitted under Section 9.1.2 (Exceptions).
>
> (b) No Direct Marketing. You must not print more than 5,000 copies of
>   sales collateral materials containing a screenshot of the Content for
>   purposes of commercial sales lead generation ("Direct Marketing") or
>   incorporate the Content as a core part of printed matter (such as
>   printed maps or guide books) that you redistribute for a fee. You must
>   contact the Google Maps API Premier sales team to obtain a direct
>   license if you desire to do either of the above.